# "arc land" Applying with wrong user

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

Strangely, I can 'arc list' and it's okay, all my work shows up and it seems to be me.

When I 'arc land', it shows up in the commit as being applied by 'admin'

I might have generated the wrong certificate when setting it up, but re-doing it didn't work.  Besides, shouldn't arc list fail?

I tried disabling the admin account, and it *still* applied the diff as admin.  My commits appear with a dot next to them because they were applied by a disabled account.

one is set up with mymail@example.com, the other mymail+phabricator@example.com.  I would try manually editing the email address to something totally different, but Phabricator doesn't seem to have the option.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phabricator links commits based on the email address, username, and real name, roughly in order. My guess is that your local Git is configured to commit as `Some User <mymail@example.com>`, so when the commit is parsed by Phabricator it looks for the user with that address and finds `admin`. Note that the author, committer and pusher of a commit can all be different (at least, in Git).

The easiest fixes are probably:

- Delete the `admin` account completely (you can do this from the "People" application); or
- log in as the `admin` account and change its email address in Settings.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, couldn't figure out how to change the email address until now.  It doesn't seem to fix it retroactively, but we'll see how future commits go.

Comment: `scripts/repository/reparse.php --message rXnnnnn` (where `rXnnnn` is the full name of an affected commit) should let you fix commits one at a time if you want.